# laravel. Проблема с route...помогите )

Tags: laravel, route

При переходе на страницу возникает ошибка связанная с route, но на других страницах где указан {{route('profile')}} не выдает ошибку....

```
Route::get('/profiles/{user}','ProfilesController@show')->name('profile');
```

Missing required parameters for [Route: profile] [URI: profiles/{user}]. (View: /home/a0298844/domains/a0298844.xsph.ru/resources/views/thread/index.blade.php)

routes/web.php

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/threads', 'ThreadController@index');
Route::get('/threads/{channel}/{thread}', 'ThreadController@show');
//Route::patch('/threads/{channel}/{thread}', 'ThreadController@update')->name('thread.update');
//Route::post('locked-threads/{thread}','LockedThreadController@store')->name('locked-threads.store')->middleware('admin');
Route::delete('/threads/{channel}/{thread}', 'ThreadController@destroy');
Route::get('channels/create', 'ChannelsController@create');
Route::post('channels', 'ChannelsController@store');
Route::post('/threads', 'ThreadController@store');
Route::get('threads/search','SearchController@show');
Route::get('/threads/create', 'ThreadController@create')->name('thread.create');
Route::get('/threads/{channel}', 'ThreadController@index');
// Route::resource('threads', 'ThreadController');
Route::post('/threads/{channel}/{thread}/replies', 'ReplyController@store')->name('post.reply')->middleware('auth');
Route::delete('/replies/{reply}', 'ReplyController@destroy');
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/profiles/{user}','ProfilesController@show')->name('profile');
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/changePassword','HomeController@showChangePasswordForm');
Route::post('/changePassword','HomeController@changePassword')->name('changePassword');
//Route::get('api/users', 'Api\UsersController@index');
//Route::post('api/users/{user}/avatar', 'Api\UserAvatarController@store')->middleware('auth')->name('avatar_path');

Route::get('/admin/{user}','AdminController@show')->name('admin');
```

в чем проблема подскажите пожалуйста)))

Answer (score 0):

Проблема во вьюхе `/resources/views/thread/index.blade.php`, где ты вызываешь хэлпер `route()` без обязательного параметра.

Для передачи параметра в маршрут нужно вызвать этот хэлпер таким образом:

```
route('profile', ['user' => $user->id]);
```

Comment: <a href="{{ route('profile', $thread->creator) }}">{{ $thread->creator->name }}</a> <small>опубликовал:</small>

вот так у меня в index.blade.php
а вот так в show.blade.php
 <a href="{{ route('profile', $thread->creator) }}">{{ $thread->creator->name }}</a> опубликовал:
                                {{ $thread->title }}
проблема в том что если главную страницу /resources/views/thread/index.blade.php он не отображает, то show.blade.php он отображает нормально, везде где написан маршрут profile кроме index.blade.php отображает...

Comment: дело в том что route у меня правильный, приведу ещё один пример, у меня написано <a href="{{ route('profile', $thread->creator) }}">{{ $thread->creator->name }}</a>, страницу отображает нормально как и направляет на пользователя, передача параметра в маршрут верная, но почему-то в index.blade.php он пишет что параметр не определен

Comment: проблема явно не в путях маршрута, везде все работает кроме той страницы о которой идёт речь, но я не понимаю почему он показывает такую ошибку

Comment: решил проблему, удалил одну строку которую не использую в бд

Comment: Молодец. Надо было также код проблемной вьюхи и контроллера привести, Тогда бы лучше понял твою проблему