# Как от заголовка статьи сделать переход на полную страницу на laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

```
<a href="#">
    @foreach ($about_s1 as $item)
        <h1>{{ $item->title  }}</h1>
        <h5>{{ $item->subtitle}}</h5>
    @endforeach
</a>

public function aboutus() {
    $about_s1 = Abouts::get();
    return view('frontend.aboutus')
        ->with('about_s1', $about_s1);

}
```

Comment: Использовать route. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/983976/laravel-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-route-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5

Comment: можете подсказать как это должно быть у меня?)

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-create-link-with-blade-templating

Comment: А вы не хотите пройти бесплатные курсы по laravel от разработчиков? Есть даже русские субтитры!

Comment: А я вроде как не просил давать мне советов.

Answer (score 0):

```
//изначально роут (web.php)

 Route::get('/articles/{id}', 'ArticleController@show')->name('articleShow');

 // контроллере ArticleController создаем метод

public function show($id)
{
    $article = Articles::find($id);
    return view('articles.show', compact('article'));
}

//во вью принимаем статью и используем по назначению, так же можно было использовать ресурс и в методе магически ловить сразу модель вместо ид статьи без поисков и танцев с бубнами
```

// вызвать созданый роут можно так

```
    <h1><a href="{{route('articleShow',[$item->id])}}">{{ $item->title }}</a></h1>

    <h5>{{ $item->subtitle}}</h5>
```